How to configure JMeter to turn off duration and enable certain thread groups
For JMeter, I am hoping to find an automated way to test my scripts. There are times when I need to validate my script on an application and it's APIs.. I have around 20 endpoints that we're hitting and I want to test them all one by one instead of running them all together.
So what I'm asking is:

How should I change the property file to uncheck duration (I just want to run it against a certain amount of iterations)
How should I enable and disable it so that it turns the other thread groups that contain the other APIs and executes in isolation when needed?
How should I output the results?

Would a powershell script need to be used in this case to automate it as well?

I have load testing tool which enables you to run against certain number of requests easily, it is still V1 so many more features are coming soon. Check it out from the below link
https://github.com/mohaidr/lps-tool

If You use Mac or Linux, you can install .Net Runtime 8 and run it using donet run LPS.dll


How should I change the property file to uncheck duration (I just want to run it against a certain amount of iterations). You can just make the duration very big, your test will finish when the last user finishes its last iteration.

How should I enable and disable it so that it turns the other thread groups that contain the other APIs and executes in isolation when needed? You can use __P() function to set the number of users. If the number of users is 0 - the thread group is not executed

How should I output the results? - it depends on what you're trying to achieve, normally people run JMeter tests in command-line non-GUI mode and generate HTML Reporting Dashboard after test

Would a powershell script need to be used in this case to automate it as well? - if you want to set JMeter properties dynamically you can use -J command-line argument for setting/overriding the values
jmeter.bat -Jproperty1=value1 -Jproperty2=valuea -n -t test.jmx -f -l result.jtl -e -o /path/to/dashboard

default values can be put in user.properties file (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)


More information:

Configuring JMeter
Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide

